# JavaScript | Iterate through JSON Object and get all the values for a specific key

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object, key

I have following JSON:

```
  [ {
    "id":1,
    "firstName":"Markus",
    "lastName":"Maier",
    "email":"markus.maier@mail.de",
    "externalId":"mmaie",
    "company":"Intel"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "firstName":"Birgit",
    "lastName":"Bauer",
    "email":"birgit.bauer@mail.de",
    "externalId":"bbaue"
    } ]
```

I want to iterate through both objects and get the value of the "email" key.. what is the simplest way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't even valid javascript. A object can't have values without keys (the inner objects). Should the outer braces be array braces?

Comment: What have you tried? What are expected results? This isn't a free code writing service and you are expected to have done some research and show your attempts

Comment: @ Michael Yes they should, i'm sorry! Edited now..
@charlietfl I'm very new to coding and i don't really have an idea where to start

Comment: Start by studying some tutorials then

Comment: @MarkusFsx see the code below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to end up with an array of just the emails, you may want to look into the `.map()` function.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Markus",
  "lastName": "Maier",
  "email": "markus.maier@mail.de",
  "externalId": "mmaie",
  "company": "Intel"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Birgit",
  "lastName": "Bauer",
  "email": "birgit.bauer@mail.de",
  "externalId": "bbaue"
}];

var emails = data.map(d => d.email);

console.log(emails);
```

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly

I didn't knew that you can address  each object with an numeric index

Answer (score 2):

Follow the code.loop through the data each object and for each object get the desired value by key.

```js
var data = [ {
    "id":1,
    "firstName":"Markus",
    "lastName":"Maier",
    "email":"markus.maier@mail.de",
    "externalId":"mmaie",
    "company":"Intel"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "firstName":"Birgit",
    "lastName":"Bauer",
    "email":"birgit.bauer@mail.de",
    "externalId":"bbaue"
    } ];
    
    for(var i=0; i< data.length;i++){
        console.log(data[i]['email']);
    }
```